# Xcode not Letting me Edit Files Because They are 'Locked'

Tags: ios, xcode, file, locked

Starting today, Xcode has suddenly stopped letting me edit files because they are locked.
 A picture of the error:
[Click Here for Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INUzR.png)

A picture to show it is **not** locked: [Click Here for Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H5g0.png)


BTW, I'm using a file that is on a USB (not saved on computer)

Comment: Do you store your password as the filename?

Comment: Working on a file stored on a USB stick is really not supported.

Comment: Working from a USB has always worked for me until now

Comment: Well don't do it. It can cause problems, as you've just discovered.

Comment: What is the file format of your usb drive?